# Read data from string and distinguish whether element is number or array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, csv

I'm reading a data from `.csv`. One of columns represents weeks on which events occur in format:

`1,2,5,6,7,8,10`

or `1-2,5-8,10`,

or sometimes even in a weird mixed way like `1-2,5,6,7,8,10`.

The minimum week number is a single `int` value (like `'1'`), the max is never greater than two-digit `int` (like `'24'`) because there are 52 weeks in a year.

**Second obstacle** is that `','` qualifies as element of array. So I have to clean string from commas and convert it to array by splitting it with `(',')` first, and then deal with main problem.

**Question:**

Does anyone have an elegant solution how to distinguish whether an element at index is range or single week and if element is an array replace it with as many elements as long the range is, for example:

`[1,3-5,7]` should become `[1,3,4,5,7]`

**What I tried:**

The best I could think of for now is to simply count the length of element at index, and if it's greater than `2` than I assume element is a range and split it by `'-'`. Then copy each element (if not array) to a new array or append new array with a range element in `for loop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would perhaps make more sense to check for presence of `-` in the item. Here's my version:

```
for item in array:
    if '-' in item:
        item_split = list(map(int, item.split('-')))
        item_list = list(range(item_split[0], item_split[1] + 1))
        array.extend(item_list)
```

Then you'll have to clean up your list to remove all "ranges":

```
array = [i for i in array if not '-' in i]
```

Assuming you need all integers:

```
array = list(map(int, array))
```

Then to remove duplicates:

```
array = list(set(array))
```

Comment: Sorry, mate, I forgot to paste second part of question I've just added, your solution is more elegant than counting length of element.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int[] ParseStringInt32ListToIntArray(string IntegerList)
        {
            int[] ret;
            bool contains = (IntegerList.Contains("[") == true || IntegerList.Contains(",")==true);

            if (!contains)
                return ret = new int[1] { Int32.Parse(IntegerList) };

                IntegerList = IntegerList.Replace("-","[").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
                var split = IntegerList.Split(',');
                ret = new int[IntegerList.Split(',').Length];
                for(int i = 0;i< split.Length;i++)
                {
                    ret[i] = Int32.Parse(split[i]);
                }

        return ret;
    }
```